# C# how to insert JSON into Google BigQuery table schema

Tags: c#, json, google-bigquery, insert

I have an array of complex JSON objects with embedded arrays of JSON objects.  By way of an example, one JSON object might look like...

```
{
    "shopID": "12194",
    "name": "Shop Name",
    "timeZone": "US\/Eastern",
    "timeStamp": "2020-11-30T13:25:13+00:00",
    "Contact": {
        "contactID": "90",
        "Addresses": [
            "ContactAddress": {
                "address1": "123 Some Street",
                "address2": "",
                "city": "A city",
                "state": "A state",
                "zip": "12345",
                "country": "United States",
                "countryCode": "US"
            }
        ],
        "Emails": "",
        "Websites": {
            "ContactWebsite": {
                "url": "www.companyname.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "TaxCategory": {
        "taxCategoryID": "2",
        "isTaxInclusive": "false",
        "tax1Name": "Tax region name",
        "tax1Rate": "0.07"
    }
}
```

I cannot modify the above format...  I am calling a public API that is returning this as a response.

Assuming that the corresponding table schema has been created in Google BigQuery, how do I simply insert this JSON as a row in to the table?

My code looks like this...

```
bqc = BigQueryClient.Create("a-project-id");
var trShops = new TableReference()
{
    ProjectId = "a-project-id",
    DatasetId = "a-dataset-name",
    TableId = "Shops"
};

# Call to my API data source that returns a JSON array of Shops...
content = await _lsrApiHelper.GetRawDataAsync(uri, currentOffset, _apiLimit);

# After call to API I deserialize the JSON response...
response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ShopResponseRoot>(content); 

# Then I want loop through Shops in the List<ShopResponse> and insert them into BigQuery...
foreach (ShopResponse shop in response.Shop)
{
    var newRow = new BigQueryInsertRow();
    newRow.InsertId = "shopID";
    newRow.Add(shop);              # This is where I am struggling
    bqc.InsertRow(trShops, newRow);
}
```

I am struggling with working out how to use a JSON or C# object to populate the data that I want inserting into BigQuery.

Any and all guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the api [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryInsertRow.html#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryInsertRow_Add_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__) it seems that you need to transform you class into `Dictionary<String, Object>` where field names are keys for dictionary (or use the overload to pass it one by one via `Add(String, Object)`)

Comment: @GuruStron... thanks... yes I clocked that.  It would mean I would have to parse through the JSON payload one key pair at a time.  That's problem #1.  Problem #2 is that I can't see from the documentation how to handle the embedded arrays.  I am hoping there's a solution out there that simply accepts the JSON payload.  Nonetheless, thanks for the tip.

Comment: TBH don't have any experience with BigQuery but I would say that either you can put them in separate tables or store as json fields (depends on your use case).